# Is this how web app + web api + external IdP + authorization work?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to wrap my head around how these work together, because I think I may be confusing something fundamental.

Given:

1. a web app (SPA, hosted in cdn)
2. one or more web apis (aspnet core)
3. an external idp (ie, azure b2c)

   1. where the app/apis have been registered as apps

**Is my understanding of the flow correct?** :

1. User signs in the spa
2. spa uses a lib (ie, `msal.js`) to perform the login, receives an `id_token` (for the web app)
3. when spa needs to call a web api, it acquires the `access_token` for the api silently
4. the `access_token` is appended to the header of the api call (as bearer token)
5. on the web api:

   1. the request arrives
   2. it can perform some authorization, ie

      - `services.AddAuthorization(opt => opt.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());`
   3. but the `access_token` may be limited, ie, `access_as_user`

Am I correct so far?

**Next question**

1. *How can each web api perform more in-depth/lob authorization?*

   1. ie: external user with id/sub `b2c-user|00001` is authorized to do `opA`, `opB`, `opC`
   2. Does each web api have to maintain its own `sub/nameIdentifier -> permissions/roles/lob logic` lookup/database (custom/aspnet core identity)?
   3. (If that's the case, I assume each web api would need some means of user management?)

For example, is this how it should be done?

[image]

---

Some references I've checked so far:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-call-api?tabs=aspnetcore

   - Code uses token acquisition to get the access token for the user. I think this is equivalent to `msal`'s `acquireTokenSilently`
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

   - authn/authz configuration for web api
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-5.0

   - adds claim to the current user in the api using middleware
   - wonder if this is how an api can map their own roles, ie:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
    {
        // Lookup local db for nameIdentifier/sub
        var repo = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserRepository>();
        var user = await repo.FindUserByExternalId(context.User.GetNameIdentifierId(), default);

        // And attach claim
        // so we can use [Authorize(Roles="...")] or
        // HttpContext.User.IsInRole()
        if (user?.Role != null)
        {
            context.User.AddIdentity(
                new ClaimsIdentity(
                    new[]
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role.Role)
                    }));
        }
    }
    await next();
});
```